# My pulse duration calculation is inaccurate. Why?

Tags: c++, arduino

I'm studying arduino. I generated pulse waves using arduino analog PWM output.
Mega pin No.4 -> 980Hz output => approximately 1000Hz => 1ms duration/pulse => 1000us

I used 50% duty cycle, so 500us pulse output.

I connected PWM output to digital input No.10 pin.

[image: pin connection picture]

And here is my code. (for HIGH pulse duration)

```
int aoPin = 4;    // analog output pin
int diPin = 10;    // digital input pin

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600); 
  pinMode(aoPin, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(diPin, INPUT);
}

void loop() {
  unsigned long highPulse = 0; // Pulse length
  unsigned long startMicros = micros();

  analogWrite(aoPin, 128);  // half duty cycle of 980Hz (arduino Mega pin No.4)


  while (digitalRead(diPin))    // calculation method 1
  {
    
  }
  highPulse = micros() - startMicros;

  Serial.print("highPulse1 = ");
  Serial.print(highPulse);
  Serial.print(" / ");


  highPulse = pulseIn(diPin, HIGH);    // calculation method 2

  Serial.print("highPulse2 = ");
  Serial.println(highPulse);
  delay(1000);
}
```

---

The result was 180 / 510 repeatedly.
The `PulseIn` function calculated accurate 500us, but my calculated duration was too short (180us).
Even `PulseIn` function was executed after my calculation function.

Why? Was My function start delayed?

Comment: I think you need to adjust method 1.  Your starting conditions aren't robust enough. 1) you get micros() too far ahead of your while() loop, and 2) you should get micros only when you KNOW you have a rising edge. (Your `highpulse` calculation is in the right place, because you KNOW you have a falling edge.)

Comment: Keep in mind that the function digitalRead is not so fast. If you want more precision it can be useful to use `PINB & 4` to read the pin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change where you call micros() the first time, so you **know** you do it at a rising edge:

```
unsigned long startMicros = 0;

analogWrite(aoPin, 128);      // half duty cycle of 980Hz (arduino Mega pin No.4)

while (digitalRead(diPin));   // wait while input is high
while (!digitalRead(diPin));  // wait while input is low

startMicros = micros();       // Rising edge detected!
while (digitalRead(diPin));   // wait while input is high

// Falling edge detected, get time difference!
highPulse = micros() - startMicros;
```

Comment: Great! I obtained accurate result with your answer. Thank you very much.